# Back Slash in Nsdictionay get from twitter feeds

Tags: iphone, ios7, nsmutabledictionary, backslash, sttwitter

I'm fetching public twitter feeds from twitter its return one 24 to 26 key value dictionary against one feed for this I'm used third party library `STTwitter` it returns array of dictionary of twitter feeds. Problem is that in dictionary value against key "text" its return some text and link too in link back slash "\" occur when i get string it return ... after before backslash I searched a lot but no solution find how I get whole text from dictionary with backslash link in ios

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: it returns "..." suppose in dictionary its full text is ht\u2069 when i get [dictionary objectforkey:@"text"] it returns ht...

Comment: I'm still confused.  When you say "it returns", *what* returns that?  It looks like you are getting what you want when you use `objectForKey:` so where is the problem?

Comment: Edit your post, add an example of what you get, and what's your real issue, with your code, what your expect and what you think is wrong.